# log4net You have tried to set a null level to root

Tags: c#, wpf, log4net

I have a WPF application that uses Log4Net to log all kinds of information.  The application runs fine and everything is logged as it should be.  However, when scrolling trhough the Output window, I found following messages:

> log4net:ERROR You have tried to set a null level to root.
>   log4net:ERROR You have tried to set a null level to root.
>   log4net.Core.LogException: Error in the application.
>   log4net.Core.LogException: Error in the application.

Here's my config file:

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="c:\temp\logs\UtexbelAppLog.txt"></file>
        <appendToFile value="true"></appendToFile>
        <rollingStyle value="Size"></rollingStyle>
        <maximumFileSize value="1MB"></maximumFileSize>
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="5"></maxSizeRollBackups>
        <staticLogFileName value="true"></staticLogFileName>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %level - %message - %line%newline%exception"></conversionPattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="WARNING"></level>
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"></appender-ref>
    </root>
</log4net>
```

I have no idea why I'm getting these messages.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You forgot to include log4net config section.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to indent my code with spaces ...

Answer (score 4):

Try to add this between your "root" quotes :

```
<logger name="LoggerName">
    <level value="WARN" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
</logger>
```

Here is the available levels, in order of increasing priority :

- ALL
- DEBUG
- INFO
- WARN
- ERROR
- FATAL
- OFF

More informations on this link, chapter "Loggers" : https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html

Comment: Thanks !  Changing the value from "WARNING" to "WARN" was enought to get rid of the error message.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `<level value="WARNING"></level>` it should be `<level value="WARN"></level>`

Comment: this should be marked as the right answer